# in javascript checking items in a string variable against an English dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have the function below that selects randomly letters from an array of all English letters (plus space, plus `<br/>`) and stores them in a string variable.

The function has a loop that generates 2,500 random characters. I would like to check which of the sequences of letters between two spaces (i.e. " " or a space and a return (" " or `<br/>`) or two `<br/>` constitute legitimate English words.

How do I do this? In particular,

1. do I need to download an English dictionary
2. how do I compare all of my strings of characters against it
3. retain the words that are legitimate? Here is the code of the
   function.

**JS**

```
function statement() {
    var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " ", "<br/>"];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2500; i++) {
        var random_letter = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        result += letters[random_letter];
    }
    document.getElementById("random1").innerHTML += result;
}
```

Comment: sorry I put "<br>" in my comments and it seems to have created hard returns.

Comment: So here is my question again:

Answer (score 0):

At first: you *need* a wordlist. If you work with a Unix OS you most probably have a medium sized wordlist in `/usr/share/dict/words` but you'll find many on the net, one short search gave http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt with about 100k words. These are already sorted so you can just put them in an `Array` word by word. Because it is sorted you can search it with a fast binary search.

You look for words between spaces and linebreaks but it is a bit ambiguous if e.g. `word<br/>word2 word3<br/>` counts as `word, word2, word3` or `word, word2 word3` so `word2 word3` would be a kind of sentence? I assume the first variation: single words, no sentences from now on for simplicity.

In the loop that produces the string, I would check every single generated character if it is space/linebreak, take the string generated so far and check that against the dictionary.

If you insist to work on the final generated string only you have to split it into single words, maybe with a regex because it is simple here:

```
var s = ("word1   word2<br/>  <br/><br/> word3   <br/>").replace(/<br[/]>/g,"").split(/[\s]+/);
s.join(",");
//word1,word2,word3,
//              the ^ last one is empty
```

Then loop over the array and check every word you found against the dictionary. Because the last entry in my poor version of splitting is empty and others might be empty, too (if you played around with it), you need to check every one if it is has something in it.

Instead of doing the dictionary search with a simple array and a binary search you can leave that hassle to the JavaScript engine by (ab)using an `{key:value}` object. (this example is sorted because of C&P from an already sorted wordlist, it does not needed to be sorted)

```
dict = {Banach:0,Bancroft:0,Bandung:0,"Banga lore":0,Bangkok:0,Bangladesh:0,
    Bangladeshi:0,Bangor:0,Bangui:0,Banjarmasin:0,Banjul:0,Banks:0,
    Banneker:0,Deleon:0,Delgado:0,Delhi:0,Delia:0,Delibes:0,Delicious:0,
    Delilah:0,Delius:0,Dell:0,Dell:0,Della:0,Delmar:0,Delmarva:0,Delmer:0,
    Delmonico:0,Delores:0,Deloris:0,Hanukkahs:0,Hapsburg:0,Harare:0,
    Harbin:0,Hardin:0,Harding:0,Hardy:0,Hargreaves:0,Harlan:0,Harlem:0,
    Harlequin:0,Harley:0,Harlow:0,Harmon:0};

dict.hasOwnProperty("Delores");    // true
dict.hasOwnProperty("foo");        // false
```

You use the key as the value here. The actual value is wasted in *this* case but you can use them for further refinement, e.g.: mark nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc. You are not restricted to numbers, of course, you can use everything, even the complete dictionary entry of that word (with pictures and music even, but that is another story).

Answer (score 0):

### this is working code implemented with node js

1) Yes, you do have to download the words, I get them from a url using the request module.

You basically have to turn the list of words from that website into an array by splitting it with a regualr expression, and also split your random generated strings with another regex. Then, you do a for loop to go through each of them, one at a time, comparing each  real word to each generated word. Like this:

```
var request = require("request");



request("http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt", function(err,status, resp){

        var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " ", "<br/>"];

        letters = letters.map(function(letter){ return letter.toLowerCase()});
        //console.log(wordsArr);
        var result = "";
        var c = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
            var random_letter = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
            result += letters[random_letter];
            c++;
        }

        if(c >= 2500){
            var randomResultArr = result.split(/<br\/>|<br\/><br\/>|\s/);
            console.log(randomResultArr);
            var matchesArr = getWordMatches(wordsArr = resp.split("\n"), result.split(/<br\/>|<br\/><br\/>|\s/));
            console.log("MATCHES: " + matchesArr);
        }

});


    function getWordMatches(wordsArr, resultArr){
    var matchesArr = [];

    console.log("WORDSARR ", wordsArr.length);
    console.log("RES ARR ", resultArr.length);


    for(var i = 0; i < wordsArr.length; i++ ){
        for(var x = 0; x < resultArr.length; x++){

            if( (wordsArr[i] === resultArr[x]) && wordsArr[i] !== "" ){
                matchesArr.push(wordsArr[i]);
                console.log("WORD MATCH : " + wordsArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return matchesArr;



}
```

### here is a sample output of it, I had to up the 2500 to 10000 to get more matches:

```
WORDSARR  349901
RES ARR  747
WORD MATCH : giros
WORD MATCH : goad
WORD MATCH : kaqa
WORD MATCH : lome
WORD MATCH : mibs
MATCHES: giros,goad,kaqa,lome,mibs
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really great. From what I see in your code, I don't have to actually download the English database. I can just direct the program to go to their servers and check my random strings, right?

Comment: Yes, you download the data with an http request, if you navigate to that URL in the code, what you see there is what is downloaded, it downloads it and stores it as a variable , resp, it does not actually save it to a file or anything.  Once the request completes, then it can be checked against your random strings